# Get Window Title Using Class With Same Class Name?

Tags: c#, winforms, window, handle, titlebar

**ANSWER: Get the processes currently running using Process.GetProcesses(); and wants you got all the processes filter through them checking if they include anything that might link to the media player using and if statement and Process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("something about media player");**

Hello Stack Overflow Users!

I am currently running into a problem developing my program. I am trying to grab the current window text from Clementine - A Media Player. The way I usually grab window titles is like this:

```cs
IntPtr ClementineWindow = FindWindow("QWidget", null);
string CurrentSong = new string((char)0, 100);
int WindowTitle = GetWindowText(ClementineWindow, CurrentSong, CurrentSong.Length);
```

But after looking into it, it will either return a number (0) or nothing. I noticed in WinSpy++ that a lot of the child windows are using the same class name "QWidget" an image can be seen below showing this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ss6qCi8.png]

Currently, I tried grabbing the window title using handle but I don't quite think I got the hang of that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all!

I should also note that the way I usually grab window handles uses the FindWindow and GetWindowText things from user32 DLL.

Comment: Have you tries something like `var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("TheProcessName").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id > 4 && p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)`, see whether you get a result and then read the `proc?.MainWindowTitle`. The other processes may not have a Window. Otherwise, you call loop the collection of Processes that have one. Or, look at the Process details and see whether one or more allow to single out the Window you're looking for. Or use UI Automation.

Comment: I will try this out and see how it goes. Thanks for a quick response.

Comment: Thank you Jimi! I modified the thing you said and messed around a bit and it works perfectly.

Comment: *Have you tries* :) lol (*sigh*). -- Well, if you found the solution, post it as an answer.